# How does Symfony differentiate services and event listeners

Tags: symfony, service, event-listener

In symfony, both services and event listeners are registered inside services.yml. Also the way they are registered is very similar.
So how does the symfony know which is service definition and which one is event listener.

Comment: Just wanted to point out that it is possible to create and register an event listener without defining it as a service.  Just more convenient to use the tagging system: https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/dic_tags.html

Comment: From the linked page: "For example, if you have a **service that you would like to register as a listener to one of Symfony's core events**, you can flag it with the kernel.event_listener tag."

Thank you, it implies services can be eventlistener also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EventListener *is* a service.

That said, there's a section named `tags` that is used for this purpose

```
tags:
  - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: [...] }
```

In this way an event listener is declared to listen to a specific event (the `[...]` part).

Read more [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher.html#creating-an-event-listener) and don't forget that, other than listeners, also [subscribers](http://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher.html#creating-an-event-subscriber) exists

Comment: OK, does that mean. EventListener is a service, which is called upon occurrence of certain event that is defined under `tags`.

Comment: @tenzin yes, basically is what you said

Answer (score 0):

An event listener IS a service, not difference